# iphone settings default value changed

Tags: iphone, settings

I am new to settings bundle programming. I have an application where some distance value is set as miles to default. After I run the application, in settings, it is showing miles.

Now if I go to settings in iPhone and change the value to kilometer, I need to get km in my application .
But on launching the application twice only, I am getting it as kilometer.

I am calling applicationenterforeground method to get the new changed settings.

How can I get the changed value in settings in my application?
I am using NSUserDefaults.

Please help me.